# Discord JS: How would I make a open/close command?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a command like ";opensales" will make a command work and if I say ";closesales" it'll disable the command.

I've tried changing a const but that only returns a `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

I've tried things such as:

```
opensales = true
```

but this didn't work.

I expected it so if I set it to true, the command would work.

I've tried changing a const but that only returns a `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

I've tried things such as:

```
opensales = true
```

but this didn't work.

EDIT: I figured out how to do based on the comments, so in case any of you want to know how, here you go:

Add `let sales =` at the top of your code. Then add this to your opensales command (for your disable command, just change true to false):
`sales = true // Enables sales.`

Comment: have you tried let

Comment: And I did that @HewwoCraziness

Comment: @Surve yeah, sorry lol, should've re-read question